# Calculating residuals from cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, svm, random-forest

I am trying to calculate the residuals from a random forest cross validation. I am working with the response variable "Sales" in this data set. I want to put the residuals into a support vector machine. I am using the Carseats data set in R. Here is my code so far:

```
set.seed (1)
library(ISLR)
data(Carseats)
head(Carseats)
 Sales CompPrice Income Advertising Population Price ShelveLoc
1  9.50       138     73          11        276   120       Bad
2 11.22       111     48          16        260    83      Good
3 10.06       113     35          10        269    80    Medium
4  7.40       117    100           4        466    97    Medium
5  4.15       141     64           3        340   128       Bad
6 10.81       124    113          13        501    72       Bad
 Age Education Urban  US sales
1  42        17   Yes Yes   Yes
2  65        10   Yes Yes   Yes
3  59        12   Yes Yes   Yes
4  55        14   Yes Yes   Yes
5  38        13   Yes  No   Yes
6  78        16    No Yes   Yes

##Random forest
#cross validation to pick best mtry from 3,5,10
library(randomForest)
cv.carseats = rfcv(trainx=Carseats[,-1],trainy=Carseats[,1],cv.fold=5,step=0.9)
cv.carseats
with(cv.carseats,plot(n.var,error.cv,type="o"))

#from the graph it would appear mtry=5 produces the lowest error

##SVM
library(e1071)

#cross validation to pick best gamma
tune.out=tune(svm,Sales~.,data=Carseats,gamma=c(0.01,0.1,1,10),
tunecontrol = tune.control(cross=5))
```

I will replace "Sales" in the SVM with the residuals from the random forest cross validation. I am having a difficult time calculating the residuals from the random forest cross validation. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I thought my work was reproducible since the data set "Carseats" is a data set provided through R. It is in the package ISLR. I'm new to R and I asked this question because I genuinely need help.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize that was an included dataset. This question should be on topic on [SO] now. We will see if we can migrate it for you.